# Sufficiently large chromatic number implies clique minor

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am trying to show that for any $n$, any graph of sufficiently large chromatic number contains $K_n$ as a minor. In other words, there exists a (minimal) function $f$ such that $\chi_G(n)\geq f(n)\implies G$ contains a $K_n$-minor. I'd then like to show that $f(n)\geq \frac12  \,f(n+1)$.

I'm totally stuck and can't see where to start, and would appreciate some help or a hint.

Comment: What makes you think it's true? Is it stated in some book? Can you give the reference? I don't know how to prove it, but I'm not sure I like your idea of first proving the existence and "then" proving the inequality. If I was going to try to work that exercise, I'd try to prove that if every $m$-chromatic graph has a $K_n$-minor then every $2m$-chromatic graph has a $K_{n+1}$-minor, thus proving both the existence of $f(n)$ (by induction) and the inequality. However, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @bof Yes. I did some digging online and it was proved in 1964 by someone named Wagner. I haven't been able to get my hands on the original paper though (and even then, it would be in German). And that does sound like an efficient approach, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

The Hadwiger conjecture asks if it is possible with $f(n) = n$.

It was proved in 1980 that it is possible to take $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(n\sqrt{\log n})$ (see [1, 2]). I think the proofs are rather accessible, though I didn't went through the whole thing.

The best bound as of today is $\mathcal{O}(n\log\log n)$ (see [3])

[1]: *Thomason, Andrew*, [**An extremal function for contractions of graphs**](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100061521), Math. Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. 95, 261-265 (1984). [ZBL0551.05047](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0551.05047).

[2]: *Kostochka, A. V.*, [**Lower bound of the Hadwiger number of graphs by their average degree**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02579141), Combinatorica 4, 307-316 (1984). [ZBL0555.05030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0555.05030).

[3]: *Delcourt M.*, *Postle L.* [**Reducing Linear Hadwiger's Conjecture to Coloring Small Graphs**](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2108.01633), Arxiv, (2021).